# Is it acceptable in React Native to set a variable on this vs. calling this.setState()?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state

Understanding that `this.setState()` will trigger a re-render of a component, if I have a view and I do not need to trigger a re-render of say, for example a View, is it acceptable to set a variable on this?  Is there any downside to doing so since I only need to reference that variable value within the scope of the View code?

For example:

```
this.adHeight = 100
```

Versus:

```
this.setState({ adHeight: 100 })
```

Comment: Setting property of element (on `this`) is completely legal in react

Comment: Thanks @madox2, so would the main reason for using this.variable = vs. setState() be to avoid triggering life cycle processing to fire?

Comment: if `adHeight` is not used in render method then it is ok

Answer (score 1):

You are not providing enough information to give you an exact answer so I will start guessing. If that `addHeight` variable is not affecting your component UI, why do you need it in your component? Is that variable a constant or it can change?

You could do:

```
const addHeight = 100;
// or
const addHeight = someConstantFile.addHeight;
// or
const addHeight = someFile.someFunction();

export default MyComponent extends React.Component {
  // use the addHeight somewhere
}
```

If that variable is not a constant, you could pass it as a prop too (but you are saying that it does not affect your `render` function so I am wondering what is the purpose of that variable). Maybe you could paste the whole component here.

But anyway, I would say yes, you can do what you are asking. I'd recommend you to use `_` thought, for example: `this._listener`. Then you could for example access `this._listener` from your `componentDidMount` and from your `componentWillUnmount` (typical example). **BUT** if you find yourself accessing that variable from your `render` function, it would mean that this variable should actually be a prop or part of your component state.

Comment: Thanks @Ferran Negre - You're right I didn't provide enough detail.  In my specific case, it's a value that's normally constant but could change if a condition in the constructor is met .. Which is actually then used in the Render fn(), so instead of defining it as a const, I was going to use this._addHeight and set it in the constructor.  From there the value wouldn't change.